# Can I ask a company about the dress code after the interview took place?

Tags: interviewing, dress-code

During my visit to the company/interview I saw different people wear different clothes, some were wearing formal clothes, and some not. I was so nervous that I totally forgot to ask the recruiter about the dress code, and now I'm expecting a call from him accepting or declining my candidacy. Would it be appropriate for me to ask this question if he calls me with a job offer?

Comment: Questions can always be asked (before or after taking the position). Just be up front about the question... "meant to ask this when I noticed some people were more casually dressed... what is the dress code?"

Comment: Would the answer decide whether or not you take the position?  If it doesn't, I probably wouldn't bother asking it while someone is offering me a job.

Comment: Anastasiya, while I appreciate that you found my answer useful, I highly encourage you to wait at least 24 hours before marking an answer as correct. You never know what someone else may post that will be even more useful and pertinent to your situation. If you see multiple answers that you like, you can always use upvotes on as many answers as you like.

Comment: You should go in for your first day dressed up as if for an interview, take a look at how people dress, maybe have a quick chat about it with your manager, and go from there. Unless, of course, if this is a sticking point to you accepting the offer in which case you should speak up at the time and simply ask. Don't make a big deal out of it.

Comment: @AndreiROM - I disagree - I would ask about the dress code after accepting the offer and completing paperwork, but before the start date. Then I'd dress at the upper end of stated dress code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Would it be appropriate? It is certainly appropriate if it will change whether you accept the job offer. However, if the dress code is something you want to know, but it doesn't have a significant impact on your decision, then I wouldn't bother asking about it now. It would be a strange question to me at such a late stage in the interview process.

Even if the dress code isn't a deciding factor, it is certainly still an important question. If you decide to take the job, that's something you can ask your manager or HR before your first day. Just say that you saw a lot of styles during the interview and wanted to know what was appropriate for your first day.

Comment: +1 - unless it's an important factor in your decision, don't bother asking.